# Is there a way to log who created a force build in CC.Net?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

When someone creates a force build on CC.Net dashboard, is there a way to log who created the build (a name of a person/dept)  or a field entry for that? Any pointers please would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is logged in the "super build results" file...can be displayed, if you write a custom .xsl for it, or edit an existing .xsl.

To see the build log, click on "View Log File" from the CCNET project page.

See if the piece of information you're after is in the file.

If so, then you can "fish" for that piece of information.

Here is an example of editing an existing .xsl file....and "fishing" for the svn-revision number.
It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it can be a basic "how to".

http://www.richard-banks.org/2007/01/add-subversion-revision-to.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the ccnet docs it's the property: CCNetUser

http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Integration_Properties

So if you're using Nant you could echo ${CCNetUser} to see who forced the build.

That's only valid if security is on. If security is not on(most likely it's not if anyone can force the build) you could present the user with a textbox or dropdown to enter/select their username. See http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Parameters for how to do that. Of course it's then up to the user whether they enter the correct information.